# Does iPhone XR have true 1080p?

Tags: iphone, ios

Since iPhone XR has 1792 x 828 resolution, does it actually have 1080p?

One thing is that, it actually might have lower resolution than iPhone 6 Plus, because iPhone 6 Plus has 1920 x 1080 Retina.

But if you consider that iPhones have been using Retina, you can say that iPhone XR's 1792 x 828 resolution is really 3584 x 1656 and is therefore way beyond 1080p. But can you really say that?

(If you can really say that, then iPhone 6 Plus actually have 3840 x 2160 and therefore really is 4k resolution?)

Answer (score 1):

When Apple states the resolution, such as 1920 x 1080 Retina, it turns out it is 1920 x 1080 tiny pixels. So it does not have 3840 x 2160 tiny pixels.

I am not sure if Apple at one point stated their Retina resolution for the Mac or iPhone / iPad without multiplying the width and height by 2. But right now, when the resolution is stated, such as 1920 x 1080, it doesn't mean it is 1920 x 1080 big pixels and that they use 4 tiny pixels to display 1 big pixel. It actually means it is 1920 x 1080 tiny pixels.

So as a result, for the iPhone XR, it is 1792 x 828 tiny pixels, and so it does not reach the 1080p resolution.  Personally, if I watch a movie on the iPhone XR, versus if it is on iPhone 7 Plus or iPhone X, I do sense that the iPhone XR picture quality is slightly less, although you can still say it is very good.